# Keeping Wordpress Menu Classes on HTML to PHP

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have this original code from my HTML Menu:

```
  <nav class="main-nav">
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <ul class="cf">
            <li class="page-collection">
              <a href="http://www.onlinepartybook.com/about/"><span>About</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-collection">
              <a href="http://www.onlinepartybook.com/features/"><span>Features</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-collection">
              <a href="http://www.onlinepartybook.com/samples/"><span>Samples</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-collection">
              <a href="http://www.onlinepartybook.com/tutorials/"><span>Tutorials</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-collection">
              <a href="http://www.onlinepartybook.com/security/"><span>Security</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-collection">
              <a href="http://www.onlinepartybook.com/processing-payments/"><span>Processing Payments</span></a>
            </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

So translating this to Wordpress I change it to this:

```
  <nav class="main-nav">
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <?php 
wp_nav_menu(array(
   'theme_location' => 'main menu',
   'container' => '',
   'menu_class' => 'cf'
));
?>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

And then place this hook on my functions.php file:

```
/* Add Menus */
function register_my_menus(){
    register_nav_menus(array(
     'main_menu' => 'Main Menu'
  ));
}

add_action('init', register_my_menus);
```

This seems to be not working well. Because of the the ff:

- It doesn't take the **ul class="cf"**
- It doesn't take the **li class="page-collection"**
- The text menu such as "**About**" and "**Features**" and so are inside a `<span>` tag which is by default WordPress will not
  do it for you.

Any idea how can I exactly customize my php codes to perfectly do this and make it perfectly work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already on the right track.

To remove the `div` element generated by `wp_nav_menu`, you should set `container` to `ul` instead of blank.

```
<nav class="main-nav">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <?php 
            wp_nav_menu(array(
                'theme_location' => 'main_menu',
                'container' => 'ul',
                'menu_class' => 'cf'
            ));
        ?>
    </div>
</nav>
```

To add `page-collection` class to each of the item, you can use the menu editor in WordPress panel.

[image: WordPress Menu Item CSS Class]

If you do not see CSS Classes field, you can enable it by expanding the **Screen Options** at the top right hand corner of the page and then **tick CSS Classes**.

It might be a tedious task but this is the simpler way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try WP NAV WALKER?

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker

The Walker class was implemented in WordPress 2.1 to provide developers with a means to traverse tree-like data structures for the purpose of rendering HTML.

Examples of WordPress objects with data that are structured in a "tree-like" way include navigational menus, page categories, and breadcrumbs.

Comment: Can you provide examples please.